# globalSearch: Angular2 sample code

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. Started creating one program in Angular1 in May 2016. Since Angular2 is ready to rock, I thought it is ideal to move to Angular2. I have this "globalSearch"(its in my attached code. Appears in 6 diff lines) function to search/filter the table data in Angular1. I assume "pipe" is its equivalent in Angular2. I couldn't find it easy to get it done in Angular2. I would appreciate if any one can point me to any sample code. Thank you.

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="/main" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Back to Prv Page</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Back to Home Page </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container"></div>
<h1>.</h1>
<h1>My Listings
  <!-- add search form-->
  <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="globalSearch.$" class="form-control"/><span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span>
    </div>
  </form>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>FIELD1_HEADER</th>
        <th>FIELD2_HEADER</th>
        <th>FIELD3_HEADER</th>
        <th>FIELD4_HEADER</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="text" ng-model="globalSearch.FIELD1_DATA"/>
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="text" ng-model="globalSearch.FIELD2_DATA"/>
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="text" ng-model="globalSearch.FIELD3_DATA"/>
        </th>
        <th>
          <input type="text" ng-model="globalSearch.FIELD4_DATA"/>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="customer_rec in customers | filter:globalSearch">
        <td>{{customer_rec.FIELD1_DATA}}</td>
        <td>{{customer_rec.FIELD2_DATA}}</td>
        <td>{{customer_rec.FIELD3_DATA}}</td>
        <td>{{customer_rec.FIELD4_DATA}}  </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to use angular 2 pipe for more information check [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

i have created one for my project

> **Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe(
    {
        name: 'filter',
        pure: false
    }
)


export class Filter implements PipeTransform {
    searchValue: string;
    transform(value: any, args: any) {
        if (args != null) {
            this.searchValue = args.text;
            //debugger;
            if (!this.searchValue) {
                return value;
            } else if (value) {

                return value.filter((item: any) => {

                    if ((args.type == 'string' || args.type == 'number')
                        && (this.getDescendantProp(item, args.key).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (args.type == 'date'
                        && (moment(this.getDescendantProp(item, args.key)).format(args.dateFormat.toUpperCase()).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private getDescendantProp(o: any, s: any) {
        debugger;
        s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
        s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
        var a = s.split('.');
        for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
            var k = a[i];
            if (k in o) {
                o = o[k];
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

> In **Component** you have to import and provide it in the list of pipes

```
import {Filter} from '../pipes/filter';
import {OrderBy} from '../pipes/orderBy';

declare var $: JQueryStatic;

//import {AuthGuard} from '../authguard/auth.guard'

@Component({
  selector: 'category',
  templateUrl: '../views/category.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [SetupService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  pipes: [Filter, OrderBy]
})
```

> Additionally In **Component** you have to set the values for search object as shown below

```
  private search: any = {};
  ngOnInit() {
    ////debugger;
    console.log("in ngOnInit CategoryComponent");

    this.search.categoryName = { key: "categoryName", text: "", type: 'string' };
    this.search.createdOn = { key: "createdOn", text: "", type: 'date', dateFormat: 'dd-MMM-yyyy' };


  }
```

> and in *View* you have to write it like this

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search.categoryName.text" palceholder="Search..." />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search.createdOn.text" palceholder="Search..." />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let cat of vm.categories | filter:search.categoryName |  filter:search.createdOn  ">
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{cat.categoryName}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{cat.createdOn | date:search.createdOn.dateFormat }}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="showdDetails(cat.categoryID)" value="Edit" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="delete(cat.categoryID)" value="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: rashfmnb : Thank you so much. I will use it as needed. Appreciated.

Comment: Hi rashfmnb: A follow up question. Do I need to update anything in systemjs.config.js?

Comment: Thanks rashfmnb. However I am not able to make it to work. Before I ask further question, I need to try few other things and debug. I will do that during the week-end and update my status on Saturday/Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Hi rashfmnb: Initially I got stuck for a long time on a browser console error of "http://localhost/.../traceur 404 (Not Found)". After reading few of the related discussions here, I had to remove commented lines inside the "mypipe1.ts" file. Cant believe "a comment" line was causing that issue. Very strange. Now that error is gone. Good. Thank you stack-overflow users.

At the end, I could make it to work finally. Nice. Thank you so so so much @rashfmnb for your assistance. Looks/Works good, EXCEPT I couldn't find a way to search ONCE at the row level. Instead I had to search MANY TIMEs once for each column. I have about 13 cols. So I had to as follows. Is there a way I could do ONE row search instead of 13 cols search? Here is my "mypipe1.ts".

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'ppfilter',
    pure: false
})

export class Mypipeclass1 implements PipeTransform {
mypipeSearchValue: string;
transform(value: any, args: any) {
    console.log("value" + value + "     args..." + args);
    if (args != null) {
        this.mypipeSearchValue = args;
        if (!this.mypipeSearchValue) {
            return value;
        } else if (value) {
            return value.filter((item: any) => {
                if (((item.FLD01 != null) && ((item.FLD01).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD02 != null) && (item.FLD02).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD03 != null) && (item.FLD03).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD04 != null) && (item.FLD04).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD05 != null) && (item.FLD05).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD06 != null) && (item.FLD06).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD07 != null) && (item.FLD07).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD08 != null) && (item.FLD08).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD09 != null) && (item.FLD09).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD10 != null) && (item.FLD10).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD11 != null) && (item.FLD11).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD12 != null) && (item.FLD12).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))
                    || (((item.FLD13 != null) && (item.FLD13).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.mypipeSearchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1))) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        return value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes you can by sending the array of all the properties in search and access them like this item["FLD02"]

Comment: Thank you rashfmnb for the info. Appreciated. I will try using it. Thanks again.